# Django ORM best practice for models depending on a field

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

Consider I have a model Attrib with a field attrib_type that provides me with the kind of inputs I may receive. For type "A", I have created AttribA, for "B" AttribB, for "C" AttribC. They have been created to keep inputs for each kind separately. On the basis of these inputs, I need to create jobs. I have come up with:

```
class Attrib(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    attrib_type = models.CharField(max_length=2)


class AttribA(models.Model):

    some_property_a = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    attrib = models.ForeignKey(to='Attrib',
                                      related_field='a')


class AttribB(models.Model):

    some_property_b = models.CharField(max_length=50)        
    attrib = models.ForeignKey(to='Attrib',
                                   related_field='b')

class AttribC(models.Model):
    some_property_c = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    attrib = models.ForeignKey(to='Attrib',
                                   related_field='c')

class Job(models.Model):
    some_property_job = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    attrib = models.ForeignKey(to='Attrib',
                                   related_name='jobs')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

Is this a good way to go or should it be done in a different way? If I may need to retrieve Jobs and Attrib for a user regularly, does the design still hold good? I am using MySQL.

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to do but your model seems strange, I would suggest:

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you exactly want to do but your model seems strange, I would suggest:

```
class Attrib(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    attrib_type = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    Meta:
        abstract=True

class AttribImpl(Attrib):
    some_property = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```